# $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] removing some ascii characters

Tags: php, html

I've looked on google and stackoverflow and just gave up because I couldn't find what I needed. Most of the questions are trying to remove the ascii characters from the uploaded file. But I have a uploading field where users can upload a file and save it to the server (For code/saves). I've uploaded a file that has 15kb and when it gets uploaded and saved, it removes ascii and other characters from the file and the file ends up being 2kb.

My uploading code:

```
<form action="./index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

and the file writter:

```
$temp_hash = uniqid();
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], "./files/" . $temp_hash . $file_extension);
```

Theses are some of the characters that get deleted in the file. Is there a way to keep all the data from the file without php removing them automatically?

```
│▓█[>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: PHP doesn't arbitrarily remove characters from file uploads: if characters are being stripped from a file, then there's additional code that is manipulating the content of the uploaded file

Comment: How are you checking this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe php is not stripping anything, but you are moving the file too soon.

When a file is being created, there is universal end of file for all formats that says that the file upload is completed. The moment few bytes are written, the file exists for the file system and you asking to move it. Having a check can avoid this problem.

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) { 

                if(copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetDirectory.$name.$extension)) { 
                    echo "Upload Success!";
                }
            }
```

Comment: This actually worked. I did what Mark Baker said and checked if the file was being manipulated but yeah: This is the full code: http://pastebin.com/npTDKb46

Comment: This is beyond bizarre. The web server is handling the file upload, only when it is complete is the PHP script ever invoked in the first place. PHP doesn't have a chance to get to see an incomplete file! Your code also isn't "waiting" for the upload to complete in any way (which wouldn't be possible in the first place).

Comment: I only pressed accepted because I added the is_uploaded_file if statement. For some reason the pastebin code doesn't work.

Comment: Just checked the documentations: @deceze is right. The steps in my code snippet seem to be breakdown of move_uploaded_file functionality. In which case, it would be instructive to see if it works for file uploads of bigger size. I worked with this one for a 20kB limit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of `move_uploaded_file` function may help you...

```
$add="./files/" . $temp_hash . $file_extension;
$tmp_name=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
@chmod($add,0777);
@copy($tmp_name, $add);
```